# Flutter doctor reports CocoaPods not installed when running through Jenkins but ok through terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, jenkins, cocoapods

Ok. I'm throwing in the towel cause I can't seem to solve this problem. Initially I didn't have cocoapods installed correctly. I followed some steps to uninstall it and then run 'sudo gem install cocoapods'. Now if I type 'which pod' I get a response '/usr/local/bin/pod. If I run flutter doctor it reports everything is ok:

```
> [exec] [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.2.1 20D75
> darwin-x64, locale en-US)
>      [exec]     • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /usr/local/lib/flutter
>      [exec]     • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (6 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
>      [exec]     • Engine revision 241c87ad80
>      [exec]     • Dart version 2.13.4
>      [exec] 
>      [exec] [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
>      [exec]     • Android SDK at /Users/rms_licenses/Library/Android/sdk
>      [exec]     • Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.2
>      [exec]     • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>      [exec]     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b08)
>      [exec]     • All Android licenses accepted.
>      [exec] 
>      [exec] [!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
>      [exec]     • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
>      [exec]     • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
>      [exec]     * CocoaPods version 1.10.2
>      [exec] 
>      [exec] [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
>      [exec]     • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
>      [exec] 
>      [exec] [✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
>      [exec]     • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
>      [exec]     • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
>      [exec]        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
>      [exec]     • Dart plugin can be installed from:
>      [exec]        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
>      [exec]     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b08)
>      [exec] 
>      [exec] [✓] Connected device (2 available)
>      [exec]     • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 11.2.1 20D75 darwin-x64
>      [exec]     • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212
```

However if I run flutter doctor through my Jenkins job:

```
[exec] [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.2.1 20D75 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
     [exec]     • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /usr/local/lib/flutter
     [exec]     • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (6 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
     [exec]     • Engine revision 241c87ad80
     [exec]     • Dart version 2.13.4
     [exec] 
     [exec] [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
     [exec]     • Android SDK at /Users/rms_licenses/Library/Android/sdk
     [exec]     • Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.2
     [exec]     • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
     [exec]     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b08)
     [exec]     • All Android licenses accepted.
     [exec] 
     [exec] [!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
     [exec]     • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
     [exec]     • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
     [exec]     ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
     [exec]         CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
     [exec]         Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
     [exec]         For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
     [exec]       To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
     [exec] 
     [exec] [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
     [exec]     • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
     [exec] 
     [exec] [✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
     [exec]     • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
     [exec]     • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
     [exec]        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
     [exec]     • Dart plugin can be installed from:
     [exec]        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
     [exec]     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b08)
     [exec] 
     [exec] [✓] Connected device (2 available)
     [exec]     • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 11.2.1 20D75 darwin-x64
     [exec]     • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212
```

We can build the ios app just fine through the terminal (& manually through xcode) but I'm stuck on this cocoapods thing. I suspect maybe its a permission thing but not sure. I've updated Flutter, xcode. When building through the terminal I see a command called "Which pod" but I doesn't seem to work when going through Jenkins. Instead it says this:

```
>          [exec] [   +4 ms] Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
>      [exec]              CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage
> on the Dart side.
>      [exec]              Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
>      [exec]              For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
>      [exec]            To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation
> for instructions.
```

Any ideas on why it won't work through Jenkins but fine through the terminal?

Thx for any help you might give.
~jeff

Edit:
I changed the permissions on the flutter directory and it now says:

```
>  [exec] [        ] Found plugin video_player at
> /usr/local/lib/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player-2.1.1/
> CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin
> code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
>      [exec] 
>      [exec] [        ] Found plugin video_player_web at /usr/local/lib/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_web-2.0.0/
> Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
>      [exec] 
>      [exec]              For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
>      [exec]            To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation
> for instructions.
>      [exec] 
>      [exec] [        ] Found plugin wakelock at /usr/local/lib/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/wakelock-0.4.0/[
> +5 ms] CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
>      [exec] 
>      [exec] [        ] Found plugin wakelock_macos at /usr/local/lib/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/wakelock_macos-0.1.0/[
> ] 
>      [exec] [        ] Found plugin wakelock_web at /usr/local/lib/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/wakelock_web-0.2.0/
>      [exec] 
>      [exec] [        ] Found plugin webview_flutter at /usr/local/lib/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-2.0.8/
> #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
>      [exec] 
>      [exec] [  +11 ms] executing: which pod
>      [exec] [  +11 ms] "flutter ios" took 2,936ms.
>      [exec]            #1      CocoaPods.processPods (package:flutter_tools/src/macos/cocoapods.dart:169:9)
>      [exec]            <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: I changed the permissions on the flutter directory and it now says:

Comment: have you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case, CocoaPods was installed under /usr/local/bin but that wasn't in my $PATH when running a Jenkins build.

Once I added it to my path in Jenkins, it started working.